# python None == None is true or false?

Tags: python, pandas, null

Is the condition `None == None` is true or false?

I have 2 pandas-dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'value':[None,20,None,40,50]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index':[1,2,3], 'value':[None,20,None]})

In [42]: df1

Out[42]:    id  value
         0   1    NaN
         1   2   20.0
         2   3    NaN
         3   4   40.0
         4   5   50.0

In [43]: df2

Out[43]:    index  value
         0      1    NaN
         1      2   20.0
         2      3    NaN
```

When I'm executing merge action it's looks like `None == None` is True:

```
In [37]: df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='value', how='inner')
In [38]: df3
Out[38]:    id  value  index
         0   1    NaN      1
         1   1    NaN      3
         2   3    NaN      1
         3   3    NaN      3
         4   2   20.0      2
```

but when I do this:

```
In [39]: df4 = df3[df3['value']==df3['value']]
In [40]: df4
Out[40]:    id  value  index
         4   2   20.0      2         

In [41]: df3['value']==df3['value']
Out[41]: 0    False
         1    False
         2    False
         3    False
         4     True
```

It shows that `None == None` is false.

Comment: No, it shows that `float('NaN') == float('NaN')` is always false (and that is by design).

Comment: `float('NaN') is not None`

Comment: `NaN` and `None` are very different things.

Comment: @ChristianDean: This is really a pandas specific issue.

Comment: @ChristianDean: well, the core of the question is that the OP hasn't spotted that their `None` input values have been *replaced* by `NaN` values, and that there is a reason for this.

Comment: OK let's leave the numbers-series. if my series is of text type, the merge also join them like they are equal

Answer (score 5):

Pandas uses the [floating point *Not a Number* value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), `NaN`, to indicate that something is missing in a series of numbers. That's because that's easier to handle in the internal representation of data. You don't have any `None` objects in your series. Even so, if you use `dtype=object` data, `None` is used to encode missing value. See [*Working with missing data*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html).

Not that it matters here, but NaN is always, by definition, not equal to NaN:

```
>>> float('NaN') == float('NaN')
False
```

When merging or broadcasting, Pandas knows what 'missing' means, there is no equality test being done on the NaN or `None` values in a series. Nulls are skipped explicitly.

If you want to test if a value is a null or not, use the `series.isnull()`and `series.notnull()` methods instead.

Comment: OK let's leave the numbers-series. if my series is of text type, the merge also join them like they are equal

Comment: @user2671057: yes, when the dtype is object, `None` is used as the null value. Pandas still special-cases nulls (such values are *skipped* when broadcasting).

Comment: So what is the solution for the merge? Fiilna to each df with different values and then merge?

Comment: @user2671057: so what exactly is the issue you are having with the merge output? Perhaps you should ask a new question focusing on your expected output for a merge. The merge looks correct to me; you have rows with nulls, and those are correctly resulting in matched joins. 2 x 2 == 4 new rows for matching nulls.